# Get page ID of page that is set as the posts page

Tags: posts, options, id

In WordPress settings you can set a page as the `Posts Page`. This can be found:

```
WP-Admin->Settings->Reading Settings->Front page displays
```

[image: Front page displays settings]

How do I retrieve the page ID that is set in this setting?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Use the `page_for_posts` option:

```
<?php
$page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
?>
```

This will return the ID of the Page assigned to display the Blog Posts Index.

Comment: Still working to this day