# Get Page ID of blog homepage

Tags: posts, pages, templates

my start page in WP shows the latest posts.

I added some meta fields to the start page in the WP backend which I want to access before the list of recent posts starts. I try to access the meta values via "`get_the_ID`", but this function always returns the ID of the first post, even when I use the hook before the loop.

How can I retrieve the ID of the page which is set up as start page?

Comment: Did you set any front page in Settings => Reading or you have default wordpress setting to `Your latest posts` ?

Comment: I solved it know with: $home_id = get_option('page_on_front');

Comment: <?php
$page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );

//output results:
echo $page_for_posts;
?>

Works for me in 4.2 wp version.

Ref:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32620/get-page-id-of-page-that-is-set-as-the-posts-page